# A semantic HTML tag for a signature

Tags: html, css, underline

While making a form in HTML which will get converted to PDF, I just realized there is no HTML tag that conveys the meaning that the underlined block is a signature (or should be signed).

Any suggestions on how to use a semantically correct HTML element for a signature?

Comment: Sounds like you simply have a problem with your <hr> positioning, it's the right tag to use.

Comment: It is possible to use underscores, view my answer :)

Comment: For the record: I disagree with the way answers are treated here.  Downvotes without direct feedback is very impolite, especially since "signature" is slightly ambiguous (think email signature).

Comment: The signature line isn't ambiguous. The correct answer is an input styled with CSS. The alternatives suggested proposed CSS styles on elements that carry no semantics at all. I was hoping for at least a semantically correct element for a signature line and since signature line is really asking for input, the input tag is the correct one. My early attempts were totally wrong.

Comment: [A shortened form of a signature block (sometimes called a "signature line")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_block).  The line above the email signature could also be called "signature line".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why not use an input? This way, you get the correct semantics. For example, screen readers will understand that the user is expected to submit information.

```css
.signature {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="signature" />
```

Comment: You are right! You are getting checked. The other alternatives do not convey the intended semantics. Input means asking for an input inside a given element. Since a signature is asking for an input, input is the correct use. I didn't think of the input tag when doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Let me add you could use a div...  use -> onClick = "this.contentEditable = 'true'; " with your border bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an input tag, then style it so that it only has a border on the bottom

```
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Simple codepen to illustrate the idea](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJXEXB)

Edit: Just noticed somebody else posted the same solution while I was typing this. What's with all the downvotes of these answers?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do to achieve this. Option number one is a div with a `border-bottom`, but that is not editable. That can be viewed here:

```css
#signaturename {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
}

#signature {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="signaturename">
  Signature:
</div>

<div id="signature">
</div>
```

The seconds option, which is editable, would be just a simple input box:

```css
#signaturetitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
}

#signature {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="signaturetitle">
  Signature:
</div>

<input type="text" id="signature">
```

---

### **EDIT**

Now just thinking of another way to achieve what you would like! :)

You could perhaps use `_`, but there would be spaces right? False, there is a work around! View here:

```css
#signaturetitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
}

#signature {
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="signaturetitle">
  Signature:
</div>

<div id="signature">
  ______________________________
</div>
```

As you can see with this one I am simply just adding the CSS property `word-spacing`.